# Can we pass parameters between two jobs in spring batch which run via spring boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

Is there way to pass parameters that are set in first job to second spring job. I am not talking about steps here, I know with executionCOntext I can pass between two steps , how about two jobs in spring batch.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could pass a reference to the `JobRepository` to your `Job`class (either in the constructor of via `@Autowired`).

It´s a weird setup, but with that you could access details about other Jobs parameters and execution.
Bear in mind that you might encounter race conditions if the Jobs you are checking are still running.

See the docs about the `JobRepository` [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.0.x/reference/html/domain.html#jobrepository)